# Webcam Access to Django Project

Tags: python, django

I am working on a Django project, and I'd like to add webcam access for users. Does anyone have any ideas on who or what I should use to implement webcam access to my site? Thanks.

Comment: Please explain "add webcam access for users" further. Allow users to access a webcam that is attached to the server? Or how to allow your Django site access to the user's webcam?

Answer (score 0):

There is support for the webcam with HTML5, but not all browsers have support for webcams, Google Chrome does have good support,

I have used this library called [camvas](https://github.com/cbrandolino/camvas) for accessing the webcam, on the client side.

But it would be helpful if you shared more intentions about your project, 
Such as Is it just to take the user's picture (such as a profile photo) Or is it a live streaming feed used for a video conference?

Comment: It's more of a video conference project.